# Error in jquery-3.0.0.js: "Unable to get property 'exports' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, jquery-migrate

I'm working on upgrading a web-app that uses jquery-1.9.1, jquery-ui-1.10.3, runs on a JBoss AS 7.0 server and uses Internet Explorer-11.

So now I'm trying to upgrade jquery-1.12.4 to 3.0.0 using the jquery-migrate-3.0.0 plugin.

On running the app, the webpage does not load and I see the following errors in the browser's console :

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'exports' of undefined or null reference
jquery-3.0.0.js (18,2)
```

Here's the corresponding code snippet from jquery-3.0.0.js

```
( function( global, factory ) {

    "use strict";

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" )
```

The error is in the last line above.

Because of this error I'm also getting "jQuery is undefined" errors in all the js files that are loaded after jquery-3.0.0.js, namely jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js, jquery-ui.js

Anyone have any insights on how to fix this? Wasn't facing this error in jquery 1.x (seems like some major change from 3.x onwards).

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have tried to create a [sample](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/OJMgVRm) using JQuery 3.0, JQuery migrate 3.0.0 and JQuery ui 1.10.3, it seems that everything works well. Besides, you could try to use different JQuery version to check it, perhaps the JQuery 3.0 version is not compatible with some plugin you are used in your application. You could find the JQuery CDN reference from [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/).

Comment: Actually the app is really big with loads of plugins being used and I have no idea about the origin of the error. Not sure how to reproduce it as an mcv example. Nevertheless, thanks for your suggestions; I suspect it might be the plugins. I shall check all the plugins now